# Open a file in a hidden directory

Tags: directory, system

I am a beginner so please assume I know nothing.
I am trying to find a BOINC file app_config.xml which should be in a this directory /var/lib/boinc-client/ but I can not find it with files. I tried using the terminal but could only find the same directories

Thanks

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details  (some Ubuntu products use *containers/confinement* so finding files can be more difficult; and currently we don't know what system you're using/asking about)

Comment: adding to the comment by @guiverc please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly with details of the commands used and errors received.

Comment: am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS release 20.04. I don't receive an error message. I tried find -iname app_config*.* and got no result. I also tried locate -i app_config*.* again no result

Answer (score 0):

That file does not exist unless you create it yourself.

> **Configuration files**
>
> The configuration is read from: `cc_config.xml`, `nvc_config.xml`, and (for each project) `app_config.xml`. If the file is absent, the default configuration is used. To create or edit the file, use a text editor such as Notepad, and save it in your BOINC Data directory or project directory.

> **Project-level configuration**
>
> This mechanism allows you to specify scheduling parameters for specific applications or app versions. It is available with 7.0.40+ client versions.
>
> **To do this, create an ASCII file `app_config.xml` in the project's directory, e.g. when the project is SETI@home: {BOINC Data directory}\projects\setiathome.berkeley.edu.**

See the bold part.

Go to the project directory and do `sudo vi app_config.xml` or `sudo nano app_config.xml` and add your specific options.

- From the [manual](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Client_configuration)
- [Some examples](https://forums.evga.com/BOINC-app_configxml-file-settings-for-GPU-Projects-m2213432.aspx)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS release 20.04. I don't receive an error message. I tried find -iname app_config*.* and got no result. I also tried locate -i app_config*.* again no result.